# left join sub query in select

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I practice SQL in [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com) and I have code below which is
wrong result because the customer name that I want to join from Customers table
generate duplicity name even customerid is different.

```
SELECT orders.OrderDate
      ,orders.OrderID   ,orders.CustomerID 
       , (select customers.CustomerName 
from Orders
Left join Customers
on Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID) as customername
FROM Orders
```

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: Any particular reason you need to use sub-query ? You can simply do a `Orders INNER JOIN Customers`

Comment: Remove the Orders table from your subquery. You don't need it to correlate the subquery to the outer. And format your code so it is readable and less confusing.

Comment: And your post is suspicious because your subquery should produce multiple rows - which would generate an error. Are you certain this is the actual query that produces the result you show?

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you need `left join` at all. Do order exists without customer? If yes, you need `LEFT JOIN`. If no, you need `inner join` as follows:

```
SELECT orders.OrderDate
      ,orders.OrderID   
      ,orders.CustomerID 
      ,customers.CustomerName
 FROM Orders
 Left join Customers on Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pulling from Orders in two places. It is not needed. Simple LEFT OUTER JOIN or simple Subquery will be fine.

```sql
SELECT orders.OrderDate
      ,orders.OrderID   ,orders.CustomerID 
       , (select customers.CustomerName 
from Customers
where Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID) as customername
FROM Orders
```

or

```sql
SELECT orders.OrderDate
      ,orders.OrderID   
      ,orders.CustomerID 
       , customers.CustomerName 
FROM Orders
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers 
ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
```